# JFileChooser can't set default selection

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I want to prompt the user for a directory in which to save some files. Thus I set up a JFileChooser, as per this simple demo app:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Demo();
   }

   public Demo() {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.setDialogTitle("Chooser test");
      chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
      chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
   }
}
```

The problem is that the "Choose" button is greyed out until the user interacts with the file picker in some fashion, even though the currently-displayed directory (in this case, the user's home directory, though my actual use case is more specific) is a perfectly valid destination. I've tried using `JFileChooser.setSelectedFile()` to set a default selection, but this still does not result in the "Choose" button being enabled.

I anticipate that in the majority of cases my users will want to go with the default directory I select for them, and they should just be able to click through the file chooser. How do I get that "Choose" button to actually be enabled?

This is on OSX, Java 6/7, in case it's relevant. Any advice/suggestions appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Tested it on Java 7 and 8 on Windows machine no issues..Worked perfectly

Comment: Okay, so this is most likely OSX being a pain then. Thanks for the cross-platform test.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [JRE problem](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7161437) in Mac Try to update JRE/JDK to latest and Try

Anyhow Add

```
  chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
```

which will set the [currentDirectory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory(java.io.File)) Location to the CurrentDirectory

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Try updating the JRE version to the latest as said in the edited post

Comment: Hm, that does look to be related. Thanks. We'll still need the workaround for the moment in our actual deployments which are stuck on Java 6, but hopefully sometime in the next few months we'll be able to upgrade to 8.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this appears, per Madhan's comments, to be specific to OSX. That in mind, I found a workaround: calling `JFileChooser.updateUI()` will force the button to notice that things have changed. Here is the updated script:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Demo();
   }

   public Demo() {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.setDialogTitle("Chooser test");
      chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
      File root = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
      chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(root.getParent()));
      chooser.setSelectedFile(root);
      chooser.updateUI();
      chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
   }
}
```

The calls to `setCurrentDirectory` and `setSelectedFile` do appear to be necessary, unfortunately. At least it works. Thanks for the assist, Madhan; I was assuming I'd been doing something wrong, so knowing it was an OS/look-and-feel problem pointed me towards looking for workarounds.

Comment: Have you tested in OSx What's the JRE version

Comment: I'm doing my development in OSX, yes. JRE is 1.7.0_67-b01.

Comment: So `chooser.updateUI();` does the trick or it's been working fine for you without that also

Comment: `chooser.updateUI()` was necessary to convince the button to enable itself.